# Why don't the XCOM soldiers say their voice quips as they run to their new positions?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I just got my son XCOM: Enemy Unknown and Enemy Within on Steam.  He immediately downloaded and tried them both.  The game is working well on two different machines but in neither case do the soldiers say their quips (e.g., "Running", "Moving at the speed of death!") when he controls them.

EDIT: Just to clarify, the "enable soldiers speech" and "native language" option are both selected.

Points of interest:

1. Both machines are slightly older hardware (about 4-5 years old) but neither has trouble actually running the game.
2. He's already tried verifying the installed files.
3. We're seeing identical behavior on both machines.
4. All other audio seems to work fine (including the cut-scenes).
5. *EDIT some time later:* He's also tried playing with the Xbox controllers instead of mouse and keyboard.

Is there a set of files that I could check manually?  I have a clean install on this machine (which definitely plays the quips on move).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the voice issue is only in the tutorial.  Once you're into real missions, the soldiers start saying their incidental lines.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if you've tried this already, just need to make sure it's not one of these first:

in the options, under "gameplay", make sure soldier speech is enabled.

Under Audio: make sure the voice volume is turned up